# Building an interface to search a .txt file depending on the user input, then print the results next to it

Tags: python, user-interface, text, python-2.7, tkinter

I've been playing around with this quite a bit and I feel like I'm making a mess of it.
I need an interface where if someone enters a word in the text field, it'll print any lines within a .txt file containing that word in the box next to it.
Here's what I have so far:

```
    import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkinter import *
    from scipy import *

    import math

    def cbc(id, tex):
        return lambda : callback(id, tex)

    def callback(id, tex):                                 
        t = Search(id)
        tex.insert(tk.END, t)
        tex.see(tk.END)
    #def retrieve_input():
    #    input = self.entn.get("0.0",END)
    def Search(id):
        with open("file.txt", "r") as s:
            searchlines = s.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):             
            if entn.get() in line: 
                for line in searchlines[i:i+1]: print line,    
                print
    top = tk.Tk()
    tex = tk.Text(master=top)                              
    tex.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)                                
    bop = tk.Frame()
    bop.pack(side=tk.LEFT)                                 
    entn = tk.Entry()
    entn.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=Y)                         
    tb = "Search"
    b = tk.Button(bop, text=tb, command=cbc(id, tex))   
    b.pack()

    tk.Button(bop, text='Exit', command=top.destroy).pack() 
    top.mainloop()
```

I'm pretty new to this, as you can probably tell - so any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: perhaps better suited @ http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is your question? What do you need help with?

Comment: @BryanOakley Hey, I'm really new to this. I can't understand why it won't print the results in the text box. I've managed to get it up to the point where it does the search but then it prints it in the command prompt. Thanks

Comment: @FredrikPihl, not on-topic for code review. We strictly improve working code, we don't help finish code.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is inserting the result of `Search(id)` but that function isn't returning anything. You need to add a return statement in that function to return the strings you want to show in the text widget.

A better way might be to pass in a reference to tne text widget to `Search` so that you can directly insert each match as you find them.